# Change the header size on a jquery UI accordion?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to set up styles for two different kinds of accordions on a site. How do I change the header size for one, but not the other?

I've tried

```
<div class="big-accordion">
 <h3 style="height:40px;"><a href="#">from your computer</a></h3>
 <div>
 ...
```

With the css equivalent:

```
big-accordion .h3{ height:40px }
```

But it doesn't look good for small heights -- the text tends to run out of the bottom of the header.

Any suggestions for doing this in a cleaner way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this is what worked out.

```
$(".accordion, .big-accordion").accordion({ event: "mouseover" });
$(".accordion .ui-accordion-header a").css({ padding:"1px 1px 1px 30px" });
```

Turns out that jquery UI automatically restyles the contents of the accordion, as shown here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 2):

I just got stuck on the same problem and the solution here didn't work so just wanted to share what worked for me.  Using jQuery UI 1.10.4

```
$(".ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header").css({ "padding-top":"2px", "padding-bottom":"2px" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a new style for your h3 in the css.

```
h3.bigheader {
   height: 40px;
}

<h3 class="bigheader">
```

Comment: my bad for not explaining better.  I know how to do the CSS. The problem here is something about the structure of jquery accordions.